# Debugging Node with Chrome Dev Tools: "Debugging session was closed" and other issues

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm

tl;dr: Getting "Debugging connection was closed.  Reason: websocket_closed. 
" when trying to debug using Chrome Dev Tools with Node.

I want to do some code-stepping of a Node app. I thought I'd give Chrome Dev Tools a try.

I'm having a few issues that are preventing me from using CDT, and I'd appreciate any help.

1) When I do the following commands in Terminal

```
node --inspect myFile.js
```

or

```
nodemon --inspect myFile.js
```

the server seems to start fine, but when I pull up the CDT Node tools through

`about://inspect`

nothing appears in the CDT Node debugger, no sources, nada.  If instead I access the tools by pasting in the URL that the above commands produce in the terminal into Chrome -- something like

`chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@521e5b7/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/node`

I get in the CDT Node debugger an announcement

```
Debugging connection was closed.  Reason: websocket_closed.
```

What gives?

2) When I add the flag "`--debug-brk`" thusly

```
node --inspect --debug-brk
```

the server doesn't even start normally.

I'm using MacOS 10.12.4, Node v6.3.1. The server is running on port 9999, there is a client app that hits the server on that port, the client app runs on port 4200.  I'm trying to debug the server code here.

(By the way, if you have another better tool than CDT to recommend for debugging Node I'd be keen to hear of it -- I have WebStorm but the process to debug Node seemed more complicated than that for CDT.)

Any help much appreciated --

Comment: In WebStorm to start debugging Node.js app all you have to do is right-click on the file you want to debug and select Debug <file name>. Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks  -- I've gotten it to work now, doing the same thing as before!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it was the weather? : following the same procedures as before, same code, I've gotten the CDT to work with the app I wanted to debug.  The warning

```
Debugging connection was closed.  Reason: websocket_closed.
```

was signaling that the app had stopped and thus there was no connection open.